Correct usage of @ContextConfiguration in a sliced spring boot integration test
I'm having issues fully understanding the ramifications of using @ContextConfiguration in a Spring Boot Integration test - or rather a sliced integration test.
I've created the following demo project using start.spring.io:
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.4'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
  sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
  testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}

which includes only spring-webflux as an additional dependency.
The project looks as follows:
DemoApplication
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

TestController
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/some/{id}")
    public Flux<String> getById(@PathVariable String id) {
        return Flux.just(id);
    }
}

SomeBean (for illustrating the issue)
@Component
public class SomeBean {
}

Let's say I want to write a @WebFluxTest. I would ideally like it to load all of my controllers and have this test be a base class for all of my Webflux Integration tests.
Let's say I have the following, simple @WebFluxTest that calls my above endpoint:
@WebFluxTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        webTestClient.get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.pathSegment("v1", "some", "{id}")
                        .build("1"))
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();
    }

}

This works exactly as expected: all my @Controller, @ControllerAdvice etc. beans are scanned.
Now let's say I want to add a protected member to my class:
@WebFluxTest
class DemoApplicationTests {
 
    @Autowired
    protected SomeBean somebean;

    // ... 
}

This fails, as expected, with a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.
Now, if I do either of the following:
@WebFluxTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SomeBean.class)
class DemoApplicationTests {
    // ...
}

or
@WebFluxTest
@ContextConfiguration
class DemoApplicationTests {

    // ...

    @Configuration
    @Import(SomeBean.class)
    static class Config {}
}

my bean can be injected but my controllers are no longer being picked up, resulting in a 404 NOT FOUND error.
If I instead write something like:
@WebFluxTest
@Import(SomeBean.class)
class DemoApplicationTests {

    // ...
}

or:
@WebFluxTest
@ContextConfiguration
class DemoApplicationTests {

    // ...
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = Controller.class))
    static class Config {}
}

the test works again.
My questions are:

Does @ContextConfiguration unconditionally override any component scanning that @WebFluxTest performs? Hence, should we avoid it in @WebFluxTest and only use it for e.g. @SpringBootTest?
Does the @Import work because @Import adds on to the context and doesn't override anything?
Why does my last solution (with @ComponentScan(includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = Controller.class))) work? The basePackages for my test class and SomeBean are the same, but since I'm filtering only @Controller, I would've expected a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException for my SomeBean injection.

